# Pandas Grouping with Max Rolling Mean Optimization

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fairly new to pandas and just wanted to post here to make sure I am using it in the most efficient way. The following code works but takes very long to run...

The code first sets up specific intervals to group the data by, and for each grouping takes a rolling avg. Once it has all of these avg's, it saves the max for that interval to a new dataframe and continues to the next interval. This is done for all workouts in the dataset ('best_interval_df') as well as the latest workout in the dataset ('latest_df') so the most recent workout can be compared to the all-time high.

Is there a different way I could be approaching this that would speed up the processing time?

Sample of data can be found here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/so4fo99q8ttkh24/samples.csv?dl=0

```
# 1 second intervals from 0-60 seconds
interval_lengths = [i for i in range(1, 61)]
# 15 second intervals from 1:15 - 5:00 mins
interval_lengths += [i for i in range(75, 301, 15)]
# 30 second intervals for 5:00 - 10:00
interval_lengths += [i for i in range(330, 601, 30)]
# 1 minute intervals for everything after 10 mins
interval_lengths += [i for i in range(660, df_samples['seconds_since_pedaling_start'].apply(
    lambda x: int(math.ceil(x / 10.0)) * 10).max() + 1, 60)]

intervals = df_samples.sort_index(ascending=True)
intervals['power'] = intervals['power'].interpolate()  # Used to fill in missing gaps in data
latest_df = intervals[intervals['workoutId'] == intervals.loc[intervals.index.max]['workoutId']]
latest_df_length = latest_df['seconds_since_pedaling_start'].max()

best_interval_df = pd.DataFrame()
latest_interval_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in interval_lengths:
    # Get interals for all time
    temp_df = intervals
    temp_df['best_power'] = intervals.groupby(['workoutId'])['power'].rolling(int(i),
                                                                              min_periods=i - 1).mean().reset_index(
        0,
        drop=True)
    temp_df['interval'] = i
    best_interval_df = best_interval_df.append(temp_df.loc[temp_df['best_power'].idxmax()])

    # Don't insert intervals for periods longer than the latest workout
    if i <= latest_df_length:
        latest_temp_df = latest_df
        latest_temp_df['best_power'] = latest_df.groupby(['workoutId'])['power'].rolling(int(i),
                                                                                         min_periods=i - 1).mean().reset_index(
            0, drop=True)
        latest_temp_df['interval'] = i
        latest_interval_df = latest_interval_df.append(latest_temp_df.loc[latest_temp_df['best_power'].idxmax()])

best_interval_df['datetime'] = best_interval_df.index
best_interval_df = best_interval_df.set_index('interval')
latest_interval_df['datetime'] = latest_interval_df.index
latest_interval_df = latest_interval_df.set_index('interval')
```

Have also now tried with generating a list of the data and then merging as opposed to appending to the df in the loop...Still very slow:

```
# 1 second intervals from 0-60 seconds
interval_lengths = [i for i in range(1, 61)]
# 15 second intervals from 1:15 - 5:00 mins
interval_lengths += [i for i in range(75, 301, 15)]
# 30 second intervals for 5:00 - 10:00
interval_lengths += [i for i in range(330, 601, 30)]
# 1 minute intervals for everything after 10 mins
interval_lengths += [i for i in range(660, df_samples['seconds_since_pedaling_start'].apply(
    lambda x: int(math.ceil(x / 10.0)) * 10).max() + 1, 60)]

intervals = df_samples.sort_index(ascending=True)
intervals['power'] = intervals['power'].interpolate()  # Used to fill in missing gaps in data
latest_df = intervals[intervals['workoutId'] == intervals.loc[intervals.index.max]['workoutId']]
latest_df_length = latest_df['seconds_since_pedaling_start'].max()

best_interval_df_list = []
latest_interval_df_list = []
for i in interval_lengths:
    # Get interals for all time
    temp_df = intervals
    temp_df['best_power'] = intervals.groupby(['workoutId'])['power'].rolling(int(i),
                                                                              min_periods=i - 1).mean().reset_index(
        0,
        drop=True)
    temp_df['interval'] = i
    # Append list with best power record for given interval
    best_interval_df_list.append(temp_df.loc[temp_df['best_power'].idxmax()])

    # Don't insert intervals for periods longer than the latest workout
    if i <= latest_df_length:
        latest_temp_df = latest_df
        latest_temp_df['best_power'] = latest_df.groupby(['workoutId'])['power'].rolling(int(i),
                                                                                         min_periods=i - 1).mean().reset_index(
            0, drop=True)
        latest_temp_df['interval'] = i
        # Append list with best power record for given interval
        latest_interval_df_list.append(latest_temp_df.loc[latest_temp_df['best_power'].idxmax()])

# Merge lists of series into df
latest_interval_df = pd.DataFrame(latest_interval_df_list)
best_interval_df = pd.DataFrame(best_interval_df_list)

best_interval_df['datetime'] = best_interval_df.index
best_interval_df = best_interval_df.set_index('interval')
latest_interval_df['datetime'] = latest_interval_df.index
latest_interval_df = latest_interval_df.set_index('interval')
```

Comment: Not had a chance to look more deeply, but generally you should not append to a dataframe within a loop - it is much more efficient to create a list of temp dataframes and use `pd.concat` at the end to combine (temp_df and latest_temp_df added to a list, pd.concat the list after the loop.

Comment: @KenSyme Could you share an example with my code of how that would work?

Comment: I tried with your code example but my change only actually shaved 1 second off (17 to 16 seconds on the sample on my laptop), so probably not really worth the change in this case!